# Can't get figure it out: mongoose update a doc inside an array inside a doc

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Well I want to update a doc inside an array by the index. My schema and code look like this

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        minlength: 4,
        trim: true
    },
    bla: []
});

// this is the example object that I get from the db
{
    "id" = "somethingUniq",
    "email" = "this@email.workdamnit",
    "bla" = [{"blabla": "something"},{"blabla":"somethingelse"}]
}

User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": "somethingUniq", "bla.1.blabla": "something" },
    {
        "$set": { "bla.$.blabla": "something new" },
        function(err, doc) {
            if (err) console.log('err in update', err);
            console.log('doc', doc)
        }
    })
```

So that blabla with index of 1 gets updated. I have tried for hours now, and can't get anything I try to work...

The end result should look like :

```
{
    "_id" = "somethingUniq",
    "email" = "this@email.workdamnit",
    "bla" = [{"blabla": "something"},{"blabla":"something new"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `$push` operator appends a specified value to an array.

( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/ )

Try `$set` in your case :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(

{   "_id": "somethingUniq",
    "bla.1.blabla": "something" 
},
{   $set:{
        "bla.$.blabla": "something new"
    }
},
function(err,result){
    if (!err) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

And make sure you're using the correct one between `_id` and `id` because you're showing both of them in your subject.

In the case you're looking for `id`, change also :

`"_id": "somethingUniq"`

To :

`"id": "somethingUniq"`

Comment: thanks for the input. Have edit the _id and $set. But my real question is about can i use the index no as identifier - fx in an array you would write arr[index no].property = value. maybe something like bla[index no].blabla?